# Is there a compact way to make std::optional<T>::value_or work on member variables of T

Tags: c++, c++20, stdoptional

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
struct S{
    int b;
    int e;
};

void fn(const std::optional<S>& maybe_s){
    int begin = maybe_s? maybe_s-> b: 0;
    int end = maybe_s? maybe_s->e : 100;
    std::cout << begin << "    " << end << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::optional<S> empty_opt;
    fn(empty_opt);
    std::optional<S> active_opt{S{11, 47}};
    fn(active_opt);
}
```

Here I want something like `value_or` but not for `S`, but for it's members.
Is there a way to do this nicely in C++?

Note that I want this to work in class initializer list, so I cant use structured bindings.

I have this solution, but I prefer to use something from `std::` if possible(ease of reading for new developers, also my solution probably has performance problems + no proper constraints, e.g. that V must be convertible to result of invoke...).

```
template<typename T, typename M, typename V>
decltype(auto) memb_or(const std::optional<T>& opt, M m, const V& default_val){
    if (opt){
        return std::invoke(m, *opt);
    } else {
        return default_val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Whilst not (yet) in the standard, [P0798R6](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p0798r6.html) (_Monadic operations for `std::optional`_) may be offering some sugar for what you're looking for, which is implemented in [Sy Brand's std::optional implementation](https://github.com/TartanLlama/optional).

Comment: `auto [begin, end] = maybe_s ? std::pair(maybe_s->b, maybe_s->e) : std::pair(0, 100);` or `auto [begin, end] = maybe_s.value_or(S{0, 100});` ?

Comment: @dfrib it is a *bit* enraging that proposal is not in C++, especially because of this part:


I couldn’t find any others

Comment: Afaict [it was recently approved for C++23](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/112).

Comment: @dfrib great news!

Answer (score 4):

Whilst not yet in the standard, [P0798R6](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p0798r6.html) (*Monadic operations for `std::optional`*) may be offering some sugar for what you're looking for, which is implemented in [Sy Brand's `std::optional` implementation](https://github.com/TartanLlama/optional).

It looks as if the proposal was just [recently approved for C++23](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/112):

> **JeffGarland commented on Jul 10**
>
> LWG completed review 2021-07-09
>
> poll: Adopt D0798R8 Monadic operations for std::optional for C++23?
>
> ```
> F  A  N
> 7  0  0
> ```